# Finding the asymptote of $\tan(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, graphing-functions

Using limits to find the asymptote of a function $y=f(x)$ is usually done with limits as : if the asymptote is of the form $y=mx+c$ then :

> $m=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ $\space$and$\space$ $c=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} (f(x)-mx)$

**Using the same formula can we also find the asymptote of $\space \space y=\tan(x)$** ?

[image: tan(x)]

---

I'm personally having problem while solving for m...please help

Thanks

Comment: The formula is valid only for asymtotes of finite slope  for $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you propose is only valid for asymptotes of the form
$$y = mx + q,$$
where $m \in \mathbb R \backslash \{0\}$ and $q \in \mathbb R$. Since $m \in \mathbb R$, these lines cannot be vertical.

On the other hand, the asymptotes you seek are of the form $x = q$. You can find them by researching all the points $\alpha$ for which
$$\left|\lim_{x \to \alpha^-} f(x)\right| = +\infty\qquad\text{or}\qquad\left|\lim_{x \to \alpha^+} f(x)\right| = + \infty.$$
This usually happens where the function does not exist, but it isn't always the case.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others replied , consider *its inverse function*

$$ y = f(x) = \tan^{-1} x $$

$$\left|\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)\right| = \pi/2  $$ which is a horizontal asymptote.

When you switch back to the original function $ x = \pi/2$  is now a vertical asymptote.

$$\left|\lim_{x \to \pi/2 } f(x)\right| = +\infty, $$ approaching from left.